# How to find total size of user attachments in active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm using Rails 6.
How to get the total size of user attachments in active storage?

======

Update:

If I have User A and User B

How to get the total size of  User A attachments?

Comment: You could use `attachment.byte_size` please refer to https://pragmaticstudio.com/tutorials/using-active-storage-in-rails

Comment: Good question! 
I can imagine an application that you would be building an application where a user can have a limit for the size of all his uploads. Thus, he would need to see the size of all his uploads.
1. Add a user_id field to active_storage_blob table.
2. Write a method to automatically add user_id to blob when user creates it.
3. ActiveStorage::Blob.where(user_id: current_user.id).map(&:byte_size).sum

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to get size of ***all attachments*** associated with some record (e.g. `user = User.first`) you can use this:

```rb
ActiveStorage::Attachment.where(record: user).map(&:byte_size).sum
```

or more efficient with such query

```rb
ActiveStorage::Attachment.joins(:blob).where(record: user).sum(:byte_size)
```

or like this

```rb
ActiveStorage::Blob.
  joins(:attachments).
  where(active_storage_attachments: { record_id: user.id, record_type: user.class.name }).
  sum(:byte_size)
```

For example this user `has_many_attached :images`

In this case you can get size only of ***all images*** of this user as:

```rb
user.images.map(&:byte_size).sum
```

or more efficient with such query

```rb
user.images.joins(:blob).sum(:byte_size)
```

or like this

```rb
user.images_blobs.sum(:byte_size)
```

Using `include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` you can convert byte size (integer) to human format:

```rb
number_to_human_size(size_of_all_attachments)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it based in @Yshmarov and @mechnicov answers

In model

```
after_create_commit :add_user

private
def add_user
files.attachments.update(user_id: self.user.id)
end
```

In controller

```
    @checksize = ActiveStorage::Blob.where(id: current_user.id).map(&:byte_size).sum
```

In view

```
  <%= number_to_human_size(@checksize) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution for the question; but this helped me solve my own case. So I'm posting it to possibly help others, as I think my case is quite common.

If you have this nested structure:

```rb
class Album < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :album_items, dependent: :destroy
end

class AlbumItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :album, counter_cache: :album_items_count
  before_destroy :purge_attachment

  has_one_attached :photo # automatically adds a `with_attached_photo` scope to prevent n+1 queries

  private
    def purge_attachment
      photo.purge_later
    end
end
```

To count total album size:

```rb
Album.first.album_items.with_attached_photo.map { |album_item| album_item.photo.byte_size }.sum
```

Note the added `with_attached_photo` scope, to prevent n+1 queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly on the database, which is much more performant than the other answers posted here.

Let's say your `User` `has_many_attached :images`.

### Finding the size of one user's images

You can find the total size of one user's images with:

```rb
size_of_all_attachments = user.images_blobs.sum("active_storage_blobs.byte_size")
```

And then, as mechnicov pointed out, you can then include `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` to convert byte size (integer) in human format:

`number_to_human_size(size_of_all_attachments)`

### Finding the size of all user's images

Also very easily:

```rb
User.joins(:images_blobs).sum("active_storage_blobs.byte_size")
```

The way this works is, as [per the documentation](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/Model.html#method-i-has_many_attached), the `has_many_attached` macro actually creates two associations in your User model, just like if you had declared them yourself:

```
has_many :images_attachments, ...
has_many :images_blobs
```

And these `:images_blobs` are regular ActiveRecord models named `ActiveStorage::Blob`, which the table name is `active_storage_blob` and they contain a column named `byte_size`, with type `:bigint`, containing the byte size.

The other answers here suggested using `ActiveStorage::Attachment.where(record: User.first).map(&:byte_size).sum`. However, this is not efficient for two reasons:

1. It will first return all `ActiveStorage::Attachment` models; these are a join model used by Rails to connect your `User` model to the `ActiveStorage::Blob` model, the latter actually containing the `byte_size` column we're after. Calling `ActiveStorage::Attachement#byte_size` will work, but it does so due to the `delegate_missing_to :blob` declaration on `ActiveStorage::Attachment`, so it uses `method_missing` which is much slower.
2. Due to #1, since `ActiveStorage::Attachment` doesn't have the `byte_size` column, it's calling `.map`, creating a needless array and loading and instanciating all these models needlessly.

So, this answer goes straight to the database and asks for the sum that's already waiting for you there.